# How do I see how many times a button has been pressed?

Tags: c, arduino, counter

I am trying to make a simple counter project just for fun. I got the main functionality down, but I now want to add some extra gimmicks. This is an Arduino project, and this is what I am using: An LCD display, a button, and a red LED. Basically, all I want is for the LCD to print out how many times the button has been pressed, and once a certain "limit" has been passed, I want the "warning stage" to initiate, which is just an LED to light up and blink. But what I need now is a way to "reset" the LCD counter to 0, and turn off the LED; a sort of override system. The way I want to do this is to click the button twice, (the same button used for the original counter), and then that will dis-engage the "warning stage". However, I only want the override system to be available after the warning stage has already been initiated. I tried to make a tracker to see how many times the button has been pushed after the warning stage, but am having trouble with figuring out how. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Here is the code I have so far. Any help will be appreciated!

```c
#define BUTTON_PIN 2
#define RED_LED_PIN 10

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#define LCD_RS_PIN A5
#define LCD_E_PIN A4
#define LCD_D4_PIN 6
#define LCD_D5_PIN 7
#define LCD_D6_PIN 8
#define LCD_D7_PIN 9

LiquidCrystal lcd(
    LCD_RS_PIN,
    LCD_E_PIN,
    LCD_D4_PIN,
    LCD_D5_PIN,
    LCD_D6_PIN,
    LCD_D7_PIN
);

int cursorLine = 0; // I don't think I need this.
int counter = 0;
int tracker = 0;

void trackerye() { // (purposely named that).
    if (counter > 5) {
        tracker++; // <-- This is wrong.
    }
    if (tracker > 2) {
        counter == 0;
    }
}

void crazy() {
    digitalWrite(RED_LED_PIN, HIGH);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(RED_LED_PIN, LOW);
    delay(300);
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(RED_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    // Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == HIGH) {
        counter++;
        delay(200);
    }
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Times Opened: ");
    lcd.print(counter);

    if (counter > 3) {
        crazy();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("OVER MAX LIMIT");
        trackerye();
    }
}
```

I tried adding different if statements and such, but none worked. I tried tracker++, but it didn't work. I am stuck.

Comment: I'm trying to boil down your specification from that wall-of-text paragraph. You are counting button presses and enabling a warning light when the count reaches `limit` which is 4. You then want to reset the count to zero if the button is pressed two more times. So, that would be when the count is 6. Correct? What is wrong with doing exactly that? I see no purpose in having the "tracker" variable at all.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. New to programming so I was just testing stuff. Although, I want the override system thing to only be available for use after say, 10 presses. That's what I am struggling with.

Comment: So, this "override system" is simply a state where pressing the button two more times will reset the count? In that case you just need to define when that happens. Still, when the counter reaches some value, it is reset. Formalize it with some constants instead of filling your program with special values: _e.g._ `warning_threshold = 4, override_threshold = 10, override_presses = 2`. Then you have: `if (counter >= override_threshold + override_presses) counter = 0;` There is nothing magic about this. Try to start thinking logically about your program's state driving its functionality.

Comment: These massive busy-delays won't work together with polling for buttons. You need to get rid of them. Buttons also need to be debounced.

Answer (score 0):

With a delay of 200ms you are not checking if the button is pressed for longer or if it's pressed slightly faster it won't be detected.

Another suggestion is rather than using 2 presses after the counter is gone over some limit is to use a long press (for example 5 seconds), this is how most things work nowadays, you need to reset something you keep a button pressed for a while and it does it.

Also, try to avoid the delay() function, it blocks your code so if you need to do something else it won't happen. This is a simple thing you are building but if you start making more complicated devices and adding more functionality it would bite you in the back side.

Here is a quick example how you could write your code and keep it "non-blocking", there is of course a lot more to write but once you get used at using millis() and variables to track time in the loop() to schedule things you will have a much better flow.

I have only added bits that go in the loop and few things before so customise it for your need, the logic is that the button press will execute only once unless you are in "reset mode" and also the button up will execute only once unless you are in your "crazy" blinking mode.

```
///...add whatever your need before 

unsigned long blink_timer = 0;
unsigned long reset_timer = 0;
unsigned long debounce_timer = 0;
int debounce_duration = 50; //ignore presses faster than 50ms

int reset_after = 5000; //the reset when enabled will happen after holding the button for 5 seconds
bool can_reset = false; // flags when the max counter is exceeded so the counter can be reset
bool reset_aborted = false;
bool can_press = true; //does the de-bouncing, basically blocks the counting if the button is constantly pressed
bool button_up_done = true;

int counter = 0;
int max_count = 5; // after this counter value we can reset the counter with a long press
int blink_after = 2; // the led will blink when the counter goes over this value
int blink_state = LOW;

void setup(){
    //...whatever you need here
}
//show the info on the screen
void showInfo(){
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("Times Opened: ");
    lcd.print(counter);
}

void loop() {


    ///anything before or after this IF block will work without blocking
    if(digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN) == HIGH && (millis() - debounce_timer >= debounce_duration) && (can_press == true || can_reset == true){
       
       debounce_timer = millis();

       can_press = false; // ignore anything whilst the button is kept being pressed unless we are in the reset mode
       button_up_done = false; //get ready for the button release

       if(can_reset == true){ //we are in the reset mode
            if(reset_aborted == true){
               reset_timer = millis(); //restart the reset procedure
               reset_aborted = false;

            }else if(millis() - reset_timer >= reset_after){
                counter = 0;
                can_reset = false;
                reset_timer = 0;
                reset_aborted = false;
            }
       }else{
            //we have reached the max and next long press will reset the counter
            // note: we are not resetting the counter yet so it will keep counting on button up
            if(counter == max_count){
                can_reset = true;
                reset_aborted = false;
                reset_timer = millis(); //remember current time
    
            }
       }

    }else if(button_up_done == false){ //the button is released and we will only execute this once

        if(can_reset == true){
           reset_aborted = true;
        }

        if(counter > blink_after){ //we are in the "crazy" mode
            if(millis() - blink_timer > 300){
                if(blink_state == LOW){
                    showInfo(); //show the info on the screen
                    counter++;

                    digitalWrite(RED_LED_PIN, HIGH);
                    blink_state == HIGH;
                }else{
                    digitalWrite(RED_LED_PIN, LOW);
                    blink_state == LOW;

                    button_up_done = true; // we have finished with the blinking so ignore the button up
                    can_press = true; // we can listen to the button press
                }
                blink_timer = millis()
            }
        }else{ //we haven't reached the "crazy" mode yet
            counter++;
            showInfo(); //show the info on the screen
            button_up_done = true; // we have finished with the button up
            can_press = true; // we can listen to the button press
        }
    }

}
```

I wrote this really quickly and haven't tested it on a device, it's more of a rough example of how you could structure your code. It is a bit large if statement and can be broken into smaller chunks by calling separate functions but may be easier to understand like this.

Comment: "You are currently doing that with a delay of 200ms" No they aren't. De-bouncing needs to be edge triggered in relation to the button press. Furthermore, humans can press buttons much faster than 200ms.

Comment: dang, completely missed to actually add the debounce! And you are correct, answer edited and re-phrased.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am fully aware of the problems delay() brings to a big block of code, and know how to avoid using it, but I didn't think I would need to in a simple project like this. (I also wasn't planning on using a delay() in the first place). I was thinking to do a long press for the reset function; but wasn't sure how. Thanks!